# java debugger not working in visual sudio code

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have installed the debugger extension
and I created launch.json file and I added breakpoint in the main function but when I click on run nothing happens and when I click on debug
it keeps loading without response I tried to reinstall the extension
and restart vscode but the issue still happens
this is the class where i added breakpoint :

```
import java.util.*;

public class CaeserCipher {
    int key;
    String message;

    public CaeserCipher(String plaintext, int secret) {
        message = plaintext;
        key = secret;
    }

    private String preprocess(String text) {
        return (text.toLowerCase()).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }

    protected String encrypt() {
        message = preprocess(message);
        int n = message.length();
        String cipherText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char temp = message.charAt(i);
            temp += key;
            if (temp > 'z')
                temp -= 26;
            cipherText += temp + "";
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CaeserCipherDemo test = new CaeserCipherDemo();
        test.run();
    }
}
```

this is a screenshot from vscode when I run debug :
[image]

Comment: Check your "args": [" "] in launch.json file. Usually, if the file name is empty or different, it doesn't run or runs a different program.

Comment: Can you post the whole code if convenient? The code you post is not enough for me to reproduce your question.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. It seemed that another VSCode extension was interfering with the Java debugger. More specifically, this extension's popup was preventing the debugger from starting ([screenshot of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvwg7.png)). Simply closing the popup fixed the issue in my case.

So I would try disabling any extensions you installed recently to see if it helps, and also check the VSCode notifications tray in the bottom right of the VSCode window to see if there are any hanging notifications and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

You must change region, Data and Time to English format.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).